# Excel HTML file <br /> not recognised until I click on the cell

Tags: asp.net, excel, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm generating an excel (2010) file with Classic ASP.

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
%>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
. . .    
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>District<br />9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The cell comes out [District9] (with no line break) until I double-click the cell. When I double-click it, the line break is finally recognised and remains so even after I remove the focus from the cell. (as it should)

District
    9

Should I be doing something else to have Excel open it and recognise the line break automatically?
(p.s please ignore mso-data-placement:same-cell. I got that one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify you have **Wrap Text** turned **On** on your whole excel page.

I could reproduce your problem by pasting :

`1
2`

into an excel Cell. Once I did <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> --- **Wrap Text**, it fixed it.

Comment: I had nowrap in the cell.
Many Thanks.